# uable to connect to mongdb Atlas from nodejs using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]This is the error I am getting . please help to resolve this

Code

```
 const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 const uri = "mongodb+srv://userName:password@saichaitanyacluster-1m22k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
 const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
 client.connect(err => {
   const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");

   client.close();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check to confirm that there is no error in connection before calling `client.db()`. The connection code should be something like this:

```
// ...Everything that was here before

client.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("There was an error connecting to the database");

    // Any other logic that you want to use to handle the error should live here.

    // Add a return statement to help avoid executing 
    // the code below that relies on a successful connection
    return; 
  }
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");

  client.close();
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: hard luck .. still same error ........ "There was an error connecting to the database"  and I am not understanding a point 1.i disabled firewall 2.i whitelisted my IP and 0.0.0.0 also allowed ... still its showing the error

Comment: Just to confirm, the `userName:password` part of the db URI are place holders right? Can you also try changing the URI to point to a local instance of MongoDB and see if that works?